# C++ error use of deleted function when declaring variable as class member

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Basically, I am creating a class, A, and another class, B, is being declared as a member of class A. If I do this, I get a use of deleted function error.

However, if I declare class B in one of the functions of class A, I do not get this error. The error I get is

....is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed... use of deleted function...

I know it is not possible for someone to explain the exact reason this is happening, but I don't really understand what this error means and why it only happens if I declare class B as a member rather than an object in a function. Any explanation of why or how to debug why this is happening?

While the code is complex, the difference I describe looks like the following.

This gives me the error:

```
class A: public Base {

  void do_stuff();

  B obj_b;
}
```

This does not give me the error:

```
class A: public Base {

  void do_stuff()
  {
    B obj_b;
  };
}
```

This also does not give me an error:

```
class A: public Base {

  void do_stuff();

  static B obj_b;
}
```

Comment: Don't describe your code in prose - show the actual code. Prepare a [mcve].

Comment: The code is very large and complex. I do not really know how to show in a question. I am only asking for some general idea of what this error means

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you are trying to copy an object of a class that is not copyable, or assign to an object of a class that is unassignable.

Comment: I added an example of the difference between the code when I get the error and when I don't get the error. edit1: I don't really see how I am copying anything. edit2: I also added another example.

Comment: @Ralff -- [You need to improve your sample](https://www.ideone.com/XNf6ry).

Comment: *While the code is complex* -- But you are the one that has the code.  Thus you're the best person right now in providing an actual example of the code that doesn't compile.  Any C++ compiler error can be duplicated with a few lines of code -- you need to show what is in `Base` and `B `, because so far, the error can't be duplicated using dummy/empty `Base` and `B` classes.

Comment: My guess would be, `B` is not copyable for some reason, and you are trying to copy an instance of `A` (in the code not shown). In the first case, when `A` has a data member of type `B`, copying an `A` requires copying a `B` too, and since the latter is not copyable, so is the former. In the other cases, `A` does not have a non-static data member of type `B`, and so copying an `A` does not require copying a `B`.

Comment: In the error message "use of deleted function" it will also say what function it is that's deleted. It is most likely `B::B(const B&)` or `B::operator=(const B&)`, or in other words copy assignment or copy constructor. You will need to define your own custom copy assignment and constructor for `B`.